# VK API не показывается количество подписчиков из группы

Tags: vkontakte-api, api

Подключил CallBack API вот мой код получения данных

```
jQuery(function($){
    $.ajax({  
        url: 'http://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById?gid=65961548&fields=members_count',  
        dataType: "jsonp",  
        success:function(e){ 
            $('#vkontakte_count').html(e.response[0].members_count)
        }  
    }); 
});
```

К сожалению ничего не выводит, вот
ВЫВОД:

```
<p><span id="vkontakte_count"></span></p>
```

Comment: Где вы указываете `access_token`? и версию нужно указывать `&v=5.80`

Comment: И протокол указывать нужно `https`

Comment: @Let'ssayPie Воу,приветствую можешь полностью запрос составить?

Comment: могу ответ полный написать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так, чтобы получить доступ к количеству участников, нужно составить правильно запрос, давай разберем твой, и учтем ошибки:

```
http://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById?gid=65961548&fields=members_count
```

Нужно изменить:

- `http` на `https`
- `gid` на `group_id`
- Указать версию `v=5.80`
- Указать `access_token`, токен можно со всеми правами можно получить [тут](https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=3116505&scope=1073741823&redirect_uri=https://api.vk.com/blank.html&display=page&response_type=token&revoke=1)

Получается у нас такой запрос: [`тык`](https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById?group_id=65961548&fields=members_count&v=5.80&access_token=)

Но, это нельзя использовать на публичном сайте, так как через токен злоумышленники могут получить все данные от вашего аккаунта, поэтому лучше всего для таких целей, как, вывод количества участников на свой сайт, использовать [`Виджеты API`](https://vk.com/dev/Community), или же использовать [`JS SDK`](https://vk.com/dev/Javascript_SDK).

Comment: Вопрос, а как скрыть токен? Или его можно не скрывать?

Comment: @МаксимХалин, в твоем случае лучше использовать php + ajax